# How many ways to number things of different categories?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose someone has prepared 11 questions for an exam. 5 are easy, 4 are moderately difficult, and 2 are hard.

How many ways to number the question from 1 to 11 (without repeating numbers), if none of the first 5 questions may be hard?

I'm guessing we'll make use of Combinations to solve this problem. Trying to boggle my mind around it with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  how many ways to choose the numbers for the hard questions?  For each of those, you just have a permutation of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You have 9 choices for the first question, 8 for the second, ...

After the first five, you can include the two hard questions back into your possible choices.